# PowerShell script to get Teams User Activity Report

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have been asked by management to create a PowerShell script that pulls the information contained in the Teams User Activity Report graph from the O365 Teams Admin Center.

I have very limited knowledge in using Microsoft Graph and it appears that it is necessary to get this information from the Teams Admin Center using PowerShell.  I have searched all over and I can't find where anyone else has even tried this so I am not even sure it is possible.  Looking for someone to point me in the right direction.  I am not a developer and have no experience with API's and have limited experience with PowerShell.  Happy to answer any questions anyone might have.

Answer (score 1):

I think as of now there is no code snippet available for getting the teams user activity report using the PowerShell, but if you want you can access them using the graph explorer:

Query:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getTeamsUserActivityUserDetail(period='D7')
```

For more Information please check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getteamsuseractivityuserdetail?view=graph-rest-1.0